# flutter error final position = await getCurrentPosition;

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTWm3.png)

I have this problem of closing the app when opening the camera, could someone help me?
I already tried permissions and updates in debug

I tried permissions, updates,
the problem occurs in the physical and when in debugging